# Column Wise Reading a Matrix from text file in C and storing them seprately

Tags: c, multiprocessing, scheduler, file-handling, matrix-multiplication

So I have 2 text files which arbitrarily contain an matrix whose size I don't know,I have a program running parallelly which computes the matrix multiplication of these two,both these programs(p1 and p2) will be running in a round robin fashion for some time quantum t, I will be using threads to parallelly read the files in p1,and have to pass these to  P2 simultaneously, so i was thinking that i will be reading file 1 row wise and file 2 column wise and pass these to p2 so that whenever p1 gets preempted in by p2 ,p2 has something to work on rather than wait for turn of p1 again until it reads the whole matrix, since during the multiplication we need the rows from first matrix and columns from second one

while searching for ways to read the file column wise all solutions I found were to read the whole file simultaneously and parse it into columns or something like that.

what i want to know is how to read the columns of second file without reading the rest so that p2 gets the required data to start the multiplication without waiting for the whole matrix

any other way to do this without reading columns is also welcome

Answer (score 0):

I know what you are trying to do with this question. You are besmirching the name of your institution and I am incredibly heartbroken and disappointed in the actions you are taking.

I wish you had read our honorable Professor's words on the difference between discussion and plagiarism. Will you be mentioning the entire internet as your collaborator in the report?

Indeed, does your group even know this reckless, shameful, inhuman, unfair, unprincipled and disrespectful action you are attempting to do?

I would personally, with a heavy heart, recommend you immediately look inside yourself, and find a way to answer this question that satisfies your inner soul, with honesty, decency, integrity, and honor.

Comment: Assuming the intention of the question isn't exactly worthy of an answer. Perhaps leave it as a comment as to suggest more investigation on the behalf of the questioner.